# Hook into an order being shipped in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to fire of an observer event once a sales order has been shipped, preferably via a hook.

So far I've only found the sales_order_* hooks to be when the user is going through the checkout and the payment but nothing afterwards.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching event `sales_order_shipment_create_after`